Flatten a List of Multi-Depth Lists
Got a nested list:
input={{{1, 11, 12, 8, 6, 2}, {{4, 5, 7, 10, 9, 3}}}, {{5, 6}, {{8, 7}}}};

Need to put all sub-lists in line:
output={{1, 11, 12, 8, 6, 2}, {4, 5, 7, 10, 9, 3},{5, 6},{8, 7}};

What is the efficient way to do so?

One of Level[input, {-2}] == Cases[input, x_?VectorQ -> x, -1] == output would be my choice.
